# How to export the virtual destructor in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, virtual-destructor

I'm working on a sample project with two modules: A and B(which links to A), using Xcode 4.4.

In module A, the symbols are hidden by the compiler flag -fvisibility=hidden. I have a class whose destructor is virtual and exported:

```
class utx
{
    int mm;
public:
    __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) utx(int m);
    __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) virtual ~utx();
};
```

And it's implemented as:

```
utx::utx(int m) : mm(m) { }
utx::~utx() { }
```

In module B, MyUtx derives from utx as below:

```
class MyUtx : public utx
{
public:
    MyUtx() : utx(5) { }
    virtual ~MyUtx() { }
}Ins;
```

While, I always get below link error for module B:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_x64:
    "typeinfo for utx", referenced from:
        typeinfo for MyUtx in main.o
```

If the utx's destructor is non-virtual, the problem goes away.

Comment: Is this not really a question about C++ instead of Xcode? Of course the question could be tagged with Mac OS X to make it specific.

Comment: Are you linking the file which contains `~utx()` ? Also, `MyUtx` derives `tux` or `utx` ?

Comment: Think that's a typo `tux` should read `utx`?

Comment: Yes, that should be typo. Also, the file contains ~utx() is linked, since if I remove the virtual before it, then I can get it linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
class __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) utx
{
  ...
```

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility typeinfo generation depends on whether your class has vfptr and adding virtual destructor can change that (if you have no other virtual functions).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this issue. Yes, exporting the whole class can work. But is there a way to export just part of the class members including the virtual destructor (not the whole class), just like what VS can do?